# It is possible to have this format in ASP .Net GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have been to this

### Name | Age | Sex | ID No.

ABC  | 24  | M   | 12312131

### Address:3rd street(colspan of whole row above)

FDC  | 26  | F   | 1232131
Address:4rd street

(see there http://i46.tinypic.com/xymna.jpg) for a while in GridView but didn't find way to add new row with every record (like repeater but i want stick with GridView to make data manageable.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a ListView instead and employ its templates to achieve the layout you're seeking:

[ListView Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with gridview templates, something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID=gView1 runat="server" BorderStyle="None" CellPadding="2"
    GridLines="None" PageSize="30" ShowHeader="False" AutoGenerateColumns=False>
<columns>
<asp:boundfield DataField=name></asp:boundfield>
<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:boundfield DataField=age></asp:boundfield>
<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:boundfield DataField=sex></asp:boundfield>
<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:boundfield DataField=id></asp:boundfield>
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: am trying like this http://i50.tinypic.com/2eoi7gx.jpg for each record in gridview there should be two row like this.